# How to group regressions by model in LaTeX output table in Stata esttab

Tags: formatting, latex, regression, stata

I am trying to have it so I have 3 different models each with two regressions underneath of them. Ideally I'd like the table columns to be organized like

```
Group 1                 Group 2                     Group 3
Reg1     Reg2           Reg3     Reg4               Reg5     Reg6
```

I tried coopting the code from [this link](https://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2012-11/msg00756.html) but got an error saying

```
0.0179 & -0.0149\sym {**} & 0.0320 & 0.00967 & 0.0320 & 0.00967 \\ & \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@@@cmidrule.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> test.tex
            
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.
```

My code with all packages I'm using is

```
\documentclass[AER,reviewmode]{AEA}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}{../images/}}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{IV Regression Results, 1990\label{tab2}}
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{D{.}{.}{-1}}}
\toprule
                    &\multicolumn{2}{c}{OLS}                    &\multicolumn{2}{c}{First Stage}            &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Second Stage}           \\\cmidrule(lr){@spam}\cmidrule(lr){@spam}\cmidrule(lr){@spam}
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Isolation, 1990}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Dissimilarity, 1990}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Isolation, 1990}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Dissimilarity, 1990}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Isolation, 1990}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Dissimilarity, 1990}\\
\midrule
Housing Supply Elasticity&     -0.0179         &     -0.0149\sym{**} &      0.0320         &     0.00967         &      0.0320         &     0.00967         \\
                    &    (0.0116)         &   (0.00642)         &    (0.0373)         &    (0.0244)         &    (0.0373)         &    (0.0244)         \\
\addlinespace
Population          &    5.69e-08\sym{***}&    2.83e-08\sym{***}&    5.58e-08\sym{***}&    2.78e-08\sym{***}&    5.58e-08\sym{***}&    2.78e-08\sym{***}\\
                    &  (1.26e-08)         &  (6.56e-09)         &  (1.05e-08)         &  (6.84e-09)         &  (1.05e-08)         &  (6.84e-09)         \\
\addlinespace
WRLURI              &     -0.0757\sym{***}&     -0.0503\sym{***}&      0.0742         &      0.0235         &      0.0742         &      0.0235         \\
                    &    (0.0203)         &    (0.0126)         &     (0.109)         &    (0.0710)         &     (0.109)         &    (0.0710)         \\
\addlinespace
Constant            &       0.269\sym{***}&       0.580\sym{***}&       0.167\sym{**} &       0.530\sym{***}&       0.167\sym{**} &       0.530\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0346)         &    (0.0198)         &    (0.0801)         &    (0.0524)         &    (0.0801)         &    (0.0524)         \\
\midrule
Observations        &         228         &         228         &         228         &         228         &         228         &         228         \\
\(R^{2}\)           &       0.188         &       0.130         &           .         &       0.017         &           .         &       0.017         \\
Adjusted \(R^{2}\)  &       0.177         &       0.119         &           .         &       0.004         &           .         &       0.004         \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.10\), \sym{**} \(p<0.05\), \sym{***} \(p<0.01\)}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a typo in your esttab command, though I can't tell for sure since you haven't posted that code. You want the range of columns in your `\cmidrule` statement, e.g. `\cmidrule(lr){2-3}`. The latex code you posted has `\cmidrule(lr){@spam}` instead.

Note the apparent typo (@spam for @span). According to the [estout documentation](http://repec.org/bocode/e/estout/hlp_estout.html#atvar), using `@span` within `erepeat` should return the column range that you're looking for. So fixing the typo should do it.

Comment: Doh! it was the span that was the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `@span` you should insert the range of columns the `\cmidrule` is supposed to span:

```
\documentclass[AER,reviewmode]{AEA}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}{../images/}}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{IV Regression Results, 1990\label{tab2}}
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{D{.}{.}{-1}}}
\toprule
                    &\multicolumn{2}{c}{OLS}                    &\multicolumn{2}{c}{First Stage}            &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Second Stage}           \\\cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-7}
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Isolation, 1990}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Dissimilarity, 1990}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Isolation, 1990}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Dissimilarity, 1990}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Isolation, 1990}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Dissimilarity, 1990}\\
\midrule
Housing Supply Elasticity&     -0.0179         &     -0.0149\sym{**} &      0.0320         &     0.00967         &      0.0320         &     0.00967         \\
                    &    (0.0116)         &   (0.00642)         &    (0.0373)         &    (0.0244)         &    (0.0373)         &    (0.0244)         \\
\addlinespace
Population          &    5.69e-08\sym{***}&    2.83e-08\sym{***}&    5.58e-08\sym{***}&    2.78e-08\sym{***}&    5.58e-08\sym{***}&    2.78e-08\sym{***}\\
                    &  (1.26e-08)         &  (6.56e-09)         &  (1.05e-08)         &  (6.84e-09)         &  (1.05e-08)         &  (6.84e-09)         \\
\addlinespace
WRLURI              &     -0.0757\sym{***}&     -0.0503\sym{***}&      0.0742         &      0.0235         &      0.0742         &      0.0235         \\
                    &    (0.0203)         &    (0.0126)         &     (0.109)         &    (0.0710)         &     (0.109)         &    (0.0710)         \\
\addlinespace
Constant            &       0.269\sym{***}&       0.580\sym{***}&       0.167\sym{**} &       0.530\sym{***}&       0.167\sym{**} &       0.530\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0346)         &    (0.0198)         &    (0.0801)         &    (0.0524)         &    (0.0801)         &    (0.0524)         \\
\midrule
Observations        &         228         &         228         &         228         &         228         &         228         &         228         \\
\(R^{2}\)           &       0.188         &       0.130         &           .         &       0.017         &           .         &       0.017         \\
Adjusted \(R^{2}\)  &       0.177         &       0.119         &           .         &       0.004         &           .         &       0.004         \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.10\), \sym{**} \(p<0.05\), \sym{***} \(p<0.01\)}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]